# Primefaces : modal Dialog : appearance

Tags: primefaces, dialog, xhtml

I use a modal Dialog and I want to modify the appearance (color and opacity).
Which skinning to use?
Thanks for your help.

```
<p:dialog id="idDial" widgetVar="wvDial" modal="true" ... />
```

Comment: Did you actually inspect the **client-side** html? or read the fine, fine **documentation**?

Answer (score 3):

Based on user guide from [PrimeFaces documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/dialog?id=skinning) you can redefine following style classes:

`.ui-dialog` Container element of dialog

`.ui-dialog-titlebar` Title bar

`.ui-dialog-title-dialog` Header text

`.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` Close icon

`.ui-dialog-content` Dialog body

Comment: I have searched for a long time on websites and stackoverflow but I cannot find the appropriate css skin. Should I use a solution with jquery or javascript?

Comment: @DenisDuval: There is no such thing as a 'css skin' it just does not exist. Not in PrimeFaces, JSF, HTML, CSS... There can be a skin composed of css and javascript. But still then the CSS is all plain CSS selectors tweak those.. .